# Why protobuf-net serializes without atrributes?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

Here is the example:

```
class A
{
    public int x { get; private set; }

    public A(){}
    public A(int x)
    {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A(1);
        A a1;
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("data", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            Serializer.Serialize(fs, a);
        }

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("data", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            a1 = Serializer.Deserialize<A>(fs);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }  
}
```

Class A doesn't have any attribute or contract, but protobuf-net doesn't throw any exception. Why?
After deserialization a1.x contains 1.

Target framework is 4.5. Protobuf-net version is 2.0.0.668, installed with nuget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a feature of v2, from [the webpage](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/)

> #### "v2" released
>
> "v2" is a major overhaul to the core engine to allow
>   much greater flexibility, and avoid a number of problems with over-use
>   of generics. It is wire-compatible with your existing data, and the
>   old API still exists. Simply: the library is much cleaner and leaner,
>   and is much more versatile for onwards development. In particular v2
>   allows:
>
> - allow use on more platforms (iOS, WP7, Mono for Android, WinRT, etc)
> - **allow use without attributes if you wish**
> - allow pre-generation of a serialization assembly, to remove all reflection at runtime
> - and generally: just more features

(Emphasis mine)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I missed it. May you provide some details please? In what cases can I serialize an object without attributes? If attributes are not necessary, how do I choose which properties to serialize if I want only some if them?

Comment: If you do not apply any attributes it is the same as applying attributes to all public properties and numbering them in the order they are declared in the file. If you only want some of them you must explicitly use attributes on your properties to mark the ones you want.

Comment: Any class which does not have attributes on it will have the behaviors set in `ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Default` applied to it.

Comment: Also I noticed that removing a constructor with(!) parameters causes throwing an exception in Serialize in this case. Why? According to what I've read about protobuf-net, it deals with parameterless constructors.

Comment: Was the constructor you you removed `YourClass(SerializationInfo, StreamingContext)`

Comment: No it wasn't. Comment out 'public A (int x)' in my example and you'll get protobuf-net exception: "Type is not expected, and no contract can be inferred: Test.A"

Comment: Maybe i should add another question about constructor and exception?